# Asp.net Mvc Routing issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have controller named PartialController and have a action method named AboutMe.
I can access my action method from localhost/Partial/AboutMe . But i want to access it from localhost/About. So i changed my route like this:

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index", id =  UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "About",
        url: "About",
        defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Partial",
                action = "AboutMe",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );
```

But i got 404 exception when trying to access AboutMe action from localhost/About. Need advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your `About Route` first. Order matters when it comes to routing, they are applied in the order in which they are defined.

```
  routes.MapRoute(
        name: "About",
        url: "About",
        defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Partial",
                action = "AboutMe",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index", id =  UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```